# How to handle data import and export from a Windows Universal app

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-8.1, windows-10

I am developing a Windows Universal app that collects results of races.  It saves each race result in a sql-lite database in an application folder so the user can view previous results.  I have further requirements, however, for saving and opening race results.

1. I need to be able to export the results of a race as a CSV file so that they can be opened by a third-party application that might be running on a separate machine on a different operating system.
2. I need to be able to export the results as an HTML file that can be uploaded/included in the user's own web site.
3. I need the user to be able to print the results (which I was thinking could just be done by printing the HTML file from a browser)
4. I would like the user to be able to choose to import the results of a race created by my own legacy application in my own format.

It seems, however, that we are restricted in a Windows Universal app to saving files to just very specific folders under very specific circumstances if we have requested that app capability.  Therefore I am getting access denied errors both saving and reading files using the FileOpenPicker and FileSavePicker.

I think I probably need to view the export and import of results in a different way, but after a lot of searching I have not been able to come up with the right and recommended solution to this.  So the question is how should I be handling the import and export of results?  Should I be using the user's documents folder, or their OneDrive?  Do I need to create a web application for my app so that the user can store results in the cloud and download them from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV and HTML are both text files with some encoding. So your question is about how to read/write files with JS.
Here is example how to create html page with [FileSavePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207871?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1):

```
var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
savePicker.suggestedStartLocation =   Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.documentsLibrary;
savePicker.fileTypeChoices.insert("Web page", [".html"]);
savePicker.suggestedFileName = "New page";

savePicker.pickSaveFileAsync().then(function (file) 
 {
 if (file) {

 var _WriteThis="<!DOCTYPE html>" + "\r\n";
 _WriteThis = _WriteThis + "<html><head><title>Web page title</title>" + "\r\n";
 // ..... 

 Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, _WriteThis, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.utf8);
           }
});
```

This example doesn't required any special rules and you can save file anywhere on you PC HDD or USD stick without setting capabilities in manifest (except system folders)
Same way you can save in csv format

Comment: I have effectively been trying this in C#, however I am getting Access Denied exceptions.  I was thinking it was due to the restrictions outlined in this... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: Nope. In this topic locations that's available without using file pickers. Just with declaration in manifest.

Comment: Yep, absolutely correct.  I had been using the file name of the file selected by the FileSavePicker to then subsequently save my file via a new StorageFile object, which didn't work.  To avoid the Access Denied error, you have to use the StorageFile object returned by the FileSavePicker!!